# JS Syntax for argument/value in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm slowly learning javascript and I'm having troubles figuring out the following syntax :

```
processfail: function () {
    $('#avatar-progress').circleProgress(
        'value',
        1
    );
},
```

I know it is going redefine the value of the argument "value" (which is set earlier in the script like this :

```
$('#avatar-progress').circleProgress({
    value: 0,
    size: 156,
    fill: { color: "#60bcff" },
    emptyFill: "#ffffff",
    thickness: 2,
});
```

All manuals I consulted show the comma is generally used to seperate arguments, and I haven't met again this type of syntax.

If I want to add a new argument to this array, how can I do that ?
I tried following their pattern like this :

```
processfail: function () {
    $('#avatar-progress').circleProgress(
        'value',
        1;
        'fill',
        { color: "#ff0000" }
    );
},
```

But it won't work. Any suggestion to correctly include the argument 'fill' ?

Is there a better alternative to this type of syntax ?

Comment: You didn't follow the pattern.  It's `propertyName: value`, with each such clause separated by a comma.

Comment: The second block is not a list of arguments, its a single argument that is an object with a list of properties

Comment: But then, how does JS know to differenciate arguments from values ? If they all are separated by commas with no "link" like a = or =>. To @Patrick : Yes indeed. I added the second block in case people might want to see where/how it was defined.

Comment: did you try to set the properties like you did before? like so:     $('#avatar-progress').circleProgress(
        'value': 1,
        'fill': { color: "#ff0000" }
);

Comment: Looking at the api [link](https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress) it looks like yo need to send an object with the new properties like this: $('#avatar-progress').circleProgress({fill: yourvalue}) and it should work.

Comment: @a.j. : No I haven't, I first wanted to understand how the first block of code works (because it actually does :/) before trying something else

Comment: @apatik, it's an overloaded function. it can take either two arguments: name and value, or a single object containing mapped names and values; I guess. That's common.

Comment: If the first block works correctly, then it is doing some processing in the function. Like if the first argument is not an object than all even arguments are the name of a property and following argument after that is the property value, so for instance `arguments[0]` would be the property name and `arguments[1]` would be the value. You would have to look at the coding of circleProgress to see how it is doing it. See [arguments reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: @Thomas So it means I can't add another propertyName + propertyValue the same way they did in the same function ? Patrick : Checking this out!

Comment: don't know, you can try it, or you can take a look at the src-code, or you can do what is mentioned all the time in the comments above: **use an object**

Comment: @apatick ahh i see. think of it like this: the first one is sort of a (key, value) pair. and the second block is taking an **object** of (key,value) pairs (edit: which is essentially, a map)

Comment: LuisKx's suggestion seems to be working, so thank you ! and @Thomas yes absolutely I did, I just wanted to fully understand the syntax used in my script before trying an alternative.